# VueJs Props not read when setting initial value in data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been struggling a lot lately on how to set the initial value in local data property. I'm using Laravel with Vue.js

I have this code below in my component

```
props: {
            user: '',
            dates: {}
        },
        data() {
            return {
                bloodTypes: {},
                bloodComponents: {},
                data: {
                    order_date: this.dates.order_date,
                    order_details: []
                },
            }
        },
```

I'm trying to get the value of the props 'dates' into the local variable.

```
order_date: this.dates.order_date
```

return undefined. Although you can see in the picture below that the props have been initialized.
[image]

> I want to know how to get the props value into my local data
>   variables.

Comment: Are you sure you are not overwriting `data.order_date` in `created` or `mounted` hooks? Can you try and set this `data.order_date` to string "foo" to check if that will persist?

Comment: I have removed mounted and created still the same. Props will work in the templates when called directly, undefined in the component.

Comment: Please try `order_date: this.dates.order_date` in `mounted()`, it should work.

Comment: how are you populating the prop ? becuase i think the prop is being populated after vue has been mounted that's why it's not getting the value on your data

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party but I thought I would share my workaround when working with async data:

```
// in the parent component
<template>
    <child :foo="bar" v-if="bar" />
</template>
```

Then you can safely follow the guide's recommended ways to initialize data value with props as so:

```
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
    return {
       counter: this.initialCounter
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Wow! Your simple solution solved my headache! I know, 4 years later, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
watch: {
  dates: {
    handler(val){
     this.data.order_date = val.order_date;
  },
  deep: true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this with, I have changed some variable name so that I won't be confused. It seems that you need to put props under watch in order to manipulate it.

```
props: [ 'user','blood_components', 'blood_types', 'current_date'],
        data() {
            return {
                list: {
                    order_date: '',
                }
            }
        },
        watch:{
            current_date: function() {
                let self = this
                self.list.order_date = this.current_date
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using computed instead?

```
    props: [
        'user',
        'dates'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            bloodTypes: {},
            bloodComponents: {}
        }
    },
    computed: {
        data: function() {
            return {
                order_date: this.dates.order_date,
                order_details: [] <= should be changed to something dynamically changed object
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: still it returns empty and undefined.

Comment: Why are you initializing props objects? Try using array for props.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Object I followed this in passing objects

Comment: type and default value can be set as object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `props` are not declared correctly.

```
props: {
  user: '',  // <-- DON'T DO THIS
  dates: {} // <-- DON'T DO THIS
}
```

When using the object syntax for `props`, each key is the prop name, and the value is either a data type (e.g., `String`, `Number`, etc.):

```
props: {
  user: String,
  dates: Object
}
```

...or an object initializer (which allows you to specify data type and default value) like this:

```
props: {
  user: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  dates: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({})
  }
},
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/24076y50x0?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FPropsDemo.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the values in the **created** or **mounted** hook.

Example: https://github.com/jserra91/vuejs_wrapper_elements_and_unit_tests/blob/master/src/components/ae/components/ea-select/EaSelect.vue